# Getting a constrained point cloud from a laser_scan

Tags: laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new in ROS and working on extracting constrained point cloud
either from laser_scan directly or by first converting the laser_scan
into point cloud and then constrained the point cloud to get the
desired point cloud.

I am using laser.bag as laser_scan data and I am trying to change the
angle_min and max from the already set values to a new desired values,
for this I am using a new pointer to input from laser.bag and changed
the angle value, but I am unable to get required result.

The angle min and max is -0.84... and 0.8... and I have changed it to
-0.45 and 0.45 to get only point cloud in between the angle.

Please help me.

(the constrained is like getting only point cloud up to 10meter range
from robot or getting point cloud only like between -45 to 45 while
laser_scan is from -90 to 90).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10113/getting-a-constrained-point-cloud-from-a-laser_scan/) by [ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/624/ravi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the turtlebot stack there is a pointcloud_to_laserscan package that includes a nodelet cloud_to_scan that iterates through a pointcloud to produce a laserscan. This is a bit backwards to what you are trying to do but with a bit of mixing things around it should be a good start.

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0